# Фоновое обновление фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, диаграммы

Есть фрагмент, в котором строится график (MPAndroidChart), сами данные для графика приходят от сервиса (сервера). Когда фрагмент открыт - все работает график рисуется.

Суть проблемы: как обновлять график во фрагменте когда он закрыт, и восстановить их когда открыт?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вм нужно записывать данные в какое-то локальное хранилище, например БД и строить график по этим данным при вызове фрагмента, а не рисовать график напрямую в фрагменте и пытаться рисовать его, когда он невидим.

Или же сделать, чтобы сервер отдавал не текущее значение, а за период на который нужен график.

Выбор способа зависит от приоритетных задач. Первый существено быстрее, второй намного более ресурсоэкономный.